# NextJS multiple public folders

Tags: next.js

I'm using a NextJs server and I need to have two different public assets folders.
Already using the regular **/public** folder to serve some assets but now I need to add a second public folder that's somewhere else on the server

My code

```js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const expressApp = express();

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare()
    .then(() => {

        expressApp.all('*', (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res);
        });


        expressApp.use(express.static('/usr/local/somewhereelse/assets', {caseSensitive: true}));


        spdy.createServer(httpsOptions, expressApp)
            .listen(port, (err) => {
                if(err) { 
                    throw err; 
                }
                console.log('Listening @:' + port);
            });

    });
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone, rookie mistake I needed to add the static route before the wildcard.

```
app.prepare()
    .then(() => {
        expressApp.use(express.static('/usr/local/somewhereelse/assets', {caseSensitive: true}));

        expressApp.all('*', (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res);
        });

        spdy.createServer(httpsOptions, expressApp)
            .listen(port, (err) => {
                if(err) { 
                    throw err; 
                }
                console.log('Listening @:' + port);
            });

    });
```